# Show close/delete votes for moderator elections

Tags: feature-request, election

In addition to showing the nominee's meta "rep" and flag weight, would it be possible to show their close/delete vote count?

It seems to me that is an important fact to know about a candidate, as presumably, it is indicative of how much "cleaning up" the user has done around the site.

Comment: You'd probably have to measure how many of those votes were valid, too. Don't want to encourage nominees to go around voting to close or delete everything to boost the count. Flag weight (flawed as it is), badges, and edit history are probably a better measure of someone's clean-up involvement than raw close/delete vote counts.  (Not to mention that it's possible to become a mod before you have the required privileges in the first place. :))

Comment: It is not so much seeing if the votes were "valid" as using it as a proxy to see how involved they are in site cleanup. In addition, flagging becomes rarer once these privileged are obtained (as flag to close gets converted to a vote), so showing this count would "correct" for that.

Comment: True. The concern I have is that this would encourage people to vote to close or delete things that don't need to be closed or deleted. I'm pretty pessimistic now, having seen a few elections where candidates made interesting choices to put themselves in a better light. Plus it'd open up the whole "is a person with 50 delete votes better at clean up than a person of comparable involvement otherwise but without delete privileges" thing. Vote counts would be an interesting data point, but I don't know if it'd be very useful.

Comment: The accepted answer to [this](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/787/high-reputation-users-having-trouble-understanding-super-user) was more of what I was thinking of, though I don't believe that SU still has this problem.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I would expect to see a correlation between lack of close votes and a lack of other successful attempts to improve the site (flagging, editing, etc.), but that's just a guess.